# std::system doesn't seem to be running my command

Tags: c++, gnuplot, std

I'm pretty inexperienced with C++, and am trying to set up a program which creates a datafile, a gnuplot script which plots the datafile, and then runs the gnuscript. The program I've set up creates the datafile and gnuplot script just as expected, but when trying to use `std::system` to run the script I don't actually get any output:

```
    std::string sysGnuCommand = "gnuplot output/data/_data.gnu";
    int errorGnuSys = std::system(sysGnuCommand.c_str());
    if (errorGnuSys == -1) std::cout << "[ERROR]: Couldn't execute GnuPlot.\n";
```

Running the program like this, the datafile and gnuplot script are created as expected, but the gnuscript is not run, nor does the system-function return an error. When I instead run the program, followed by manually running `gnuplot output/data/_data.gnu` in the console I get the exact output I expect. How come the std::system command doesn't seem to run?

**EDIT:** If I change the directory to search for with gnuplot to an incorrect one, gnuplot properly returns an error. By adding a line with console output to the gnuplot script though, I find that `std::system` does not actually run `_data.gnu` when called on in the program. I've checked to make sure `std::system` is working in the expected directory, so the issue does definitely seem to be there somewhere.

**EDIT 2:**

```
int main(){
    FileSystem _fileManager;

    std::string _outDir = "output/data/";

    create_folder_path(_outDir + "/plots");

    _fileManager.set_directory(_outDir);

    std::string currentName;
    currentName = "_data";

    std::string _csvOutput;
    _csvOutput = currentName + ".csv";
    _fileManager.create_file(_csvOutput);

    std::string _gnuScriptOutput;
    _gnuScriptOutput = currentName + ".gnu";
    _fileManager.create_file(_gnuScriptOutput);


    std::string _gnuText = 
        "system \"dir\"\n"
        "set terminal postscript enhanced color eps\n"
        "set cbrange [0:25]\n"
        "set output \"" + _outDir + "plots/" + currentName + ".ps\"\n"
        "plot \"" + _outDir + _csvOutput + "\" using 1:2:3 notitle with image";
    _fileManager.add_line(_gnuScriptOutput, _gnuText);

    for(int x = 1; x <= 5; ++x){
        for(int y = 1; y <= 5; ++y){
            std::vector<double> outputLine;
            outputLine.push_back(x);
            outputLine.push_back(y);
            outputLine.push_back(x*y);
            _fileManager.add_line(_csvOutput, outputLine);
            outputLine.clear();
        }
    }

    std::string sysGnuCommand = "gnuplot " + _outDir + _gnuScriptOutput;
    int errorGnuSys = std::system(sysGnuCommand.c_str());
    if (errorGnuSys != 0) std::cout << "[ERROR]: Couldn't execute GnuPlot.\n";
}
```

Here's the code for my `main` function. `FileSystem` is just a class to simplify data handling, and works exactly as expected - I am confident it is not the source of the issue. I'm not working in an IDE either, so that shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: What is the value of `errorGnuSys` actually?  -1 is not usually the error it would return anyway, so your error checking will never trigger like this.

Comment: I checked, and `errorGnuSys` is 0.

Comment: I'd run it under `strace -f` and see what comes out.

Comment: How would I use  `strace -f`properly? I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

The information is too less, I can not point out what's wrong with you code.

But I think you can run `system("dir")` to check out if your work directory is right.

You konw, if you run/debug a program in an IDE, the work directory may not meet your expectation.

Comment: `system("dir")` tells me I'm working in the directory one step above the `/output/` directory, which is the same directory I'm running my program from.